# VB 2010 SendMessage: sending binary data to another app

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, arrays, sendmessage

I'm trying to send structured data from a VB 2010 app that I'm developing to an existing library which expects strings to be converted into byte arrays.  I'm having trouble with the sending the data as byte arrays - I can send the plain string that should be converted to bytes to a test program that I've written.

Here are the two apps.  Firstly the listener process:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class frmTest

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    If m.Msg = frmTest.WM_COPYDATA Then
        Dim data As CopyData
        Dim message As String

        ' get the data...
        data = CType(m.GetLParam(GetType(CopyData)), CopyData)

        message = data.lpData
        ' add the message
        txtTest.Text = message

        ' let them know we processed the message...
        m.Result = New IntPtr(1)
    Else
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End If
End Sub

Private Function UnicodeBytesToString(ByVal bytes() As Byte) As String

    Return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes)
End Function

Private Const WM_COPYDATA As Integer = &H4A

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Private Structure CopyData
    Public dwData As IntPtr
    Public cbData As Integer
    Public lpData As String
End Structure
End Class
```

Secondly the process that sends the data:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class frmMain

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Private Structure CopyData
    Public dwData As IntPtr
    Public cbData As Integer
    Public lpData As String
End Structure

Private Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32" _
 (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
  ByVal Msg As Integer, _
  ByVal wParam As IntPtr, _
  ByRef lParam As CopyData) As Boolean

Private Declare Auto Function FindWindow Lib "user32" _
 (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
  ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr

Private Const WM_COPYDATA As Integer = &H4A

Private Sub cmdSend_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSend.Click


    Dim ClientWindow As IntPtr
    Dim a() As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses

    For Each p In a
        Console.WriteLine(p.ProcessName)
        If p.ProcessName = "Listener" Then
            ClientWindow = p.MainWindowHandle
            Exit For
        End If
    Next


    ' make sure we found an active client window
    If Not ClientWindow.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then

        ' if there is text to send
        If txtText.Text.Length > 0 Then
            Dim message As String = txtText.Text
            Dim data As CopyData

            ' set up the data...
            data.lpData = message
            data.cbData = message.Length * Marshal.SystemDefaultCharSize

            ' send the data
            frmMain.SendMessage(ClientWindow, frmMain.WM_COPYDATA, Me.Handle, data)

        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Could Not Find Active Client Window.")
    End If
End Sub

Private Function UnicodeStringToBytes(
ByVal str As String) As Byte()

    Return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str)
End Function

End Class
```

This all works but if I change 'Public lpData As String' to 'Public lpData As Byte()' in both and then amend 'data.lpData = message' to 'data.lpData = UnicodeStringToBytes(message)' in the sender process and 'message = data.lpData' to 'message = UnicodeBytesToString(data.lpData)' in the listener process it crashes.

How can I send a string encoded as a byte array from the sender to the listener so that the listener can decode it back to a string ?

I realise it would be easier to send the string as a string but the existing library needs it as a byte array so I'm trying to get my sender working against this test listener where I can see what's happening.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I'm not that familiar with VB, I've made the changes in the receiving app but I'm not sure what you mean in the sending app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable-length arrays in structures are always a pain.

Declare `lpData` as `IntPtr` in both applications.

Then in the sending app:

```
' set up the data...
Dim string_bytes = UnicodeStringToBytes(message)

Dim pinned = GCHandle.Alloc(string_bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned)
Try
    data.dwData = New IntPtr(message.Length)
    data.cbData = string_bytes.Length
    data.lpData = pinned.AddrOfPinnedObject()

    ' send the data
    frmMain.SendMessage(ClientWindow, frmMain.WM_COPYDATA, Me.Handle, data)
Finally
    If pinned.IsAllocated Then pinned.Free()
End Try
```

In the receiving app:

```
' get the data...
data = CType(m.GetLParam(GetType(CopyData)), CopyData)

Dim message(0 To data.cbData - 1) As Byte
Marshal.Copy(data.lpData, message, 0, data.cbData)

' add the message
txtTest.Text = UnicodeBytesToString(message)
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you that worked perfectly.  Now to get my head around what you did :-)